# why OAuth request_token using openid4java is missing in the google's response?

Tags: java, oauth, openid, google-openid

I have succeed using openID and OAuth separately, but I can't make them work together.

Am I doing something incorrect:

```
String userSuppliedString = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id";
ConsumerManager manager = new ConsumerManager();
String returnToUrl = "http://example.com:8080/app-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/GAuthorize";
List<DiscoveryInformation> discoveries = manager.discover(userSuppliedString);        
DiscoveryInformation discovered = manager.associate(discoveries);            
AuthRequest authReq = manager.authenticate(discovered, returnToUrl);
session.put("openID-discoveries", discovered);
FetchRequest fetch = FetchRequest.createFetchRequest();
fetch.addAttribute("email","http://schema.openid.net/contact/email",true);                                                                  
fetch.addAttribute("oauth", "http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0",true);
fetch.addAttribute("consumer","example.com" ,true);
fetch.addAttribute("scope","http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" ,true);
authReq.addExtension(fetch);            
destinationUrl = authReq.getDestinationUrl(true);
```

then destinationUrl is

https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3A8080%2FgoogleTest%2Fauthorize&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3A8080%2FgoogleTest%2Fauthorize&openid.assoc_handle=AMlYA9WVkS_oVNWtczp3zr3sS8lxR4DlnDS0fe-zMIhmepQsByLqvGnc8qeJwypiRQAuQvdw&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request&openid.ext1.type.email=http%3A%2F%2Fschema.openid.net%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.type.oauth=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Foauth%2F1.0&openid.ext1.type.consumer=example.com&openid.ext1.type.scope=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcalendar%2Ffeeds%2F&openid.ext1.required=email%2Coauth%2Cconsumer%2Cscope"

but in the response from google **request_token is missing**

http://example.com:8080/googleTest/authorize?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2011-11-29T17%3A38%3A39ZEU2iBVXr_zQG5Q&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3A8080%2FgoogleTest%2Fauthorize&openid.assoc_handle=AMlYA9WVkS_oVNWtczp3zr3sS8lxR4DlnDS0fe-zMIhmepQsByLqvGnc8qeJwypiRQAuQvdw&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.email%2Cext1.value.email&openid.sig=5jUnS1jT16hIDCAjv%2BwAL1jopo6YHgfZ3nUUgFpeXlw%3D&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawk8YPjBcnQrqXW8tzK3aFVop63E7q-JrCE&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawk8YPjBcnQrqXW8tzK3aFVop63E7q-JrCE&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response&openid.ext1.type.email=http%3A%2F%2Fschema.openid.net%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.value.email=example%40gmail.com

**why?**

Answer (score 1):

In the above code, you have added OAuth extension parameters with the Attribute Exchange extension parameters. But since OAuth and Attribute Exchange are different extensions, therefore you have to create a different extension message for OAuth parameters and then add it to Authentication request message.

But since there is no mechanism to add OAuth parameters to the Authentication message, therefore you'll have to create such a mechanism. You can get information about it in the following link
http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/wiki/ExtensionHowTo

You can then use the code provided in the following link to hard code this mechanism
http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/issues/detail?id=110&q=oauth

Comment: Thank you very much for he answer, I ll try to find the code I was using and give a shot to your suggestion.